# BIND server won't resolve some legitimate domains

Tags: bind, dns-zone

I have setup a BIND9 server on host so that I can block malicious websites on my network. I have used [OZNU's DNS Zone Blacklist tool](https://github.com/oznu/dns-zone-blacklist) to generate the desired blacklist. Overall, it works really well. However, I encountered some issues with some legitimate domains, such as www.austrian.com. The DNS will resolve to a `0.0.0.0` ip.

Using `dig @localhost www.austrian.com` results into the following output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1-Debian <<>> @localhost www.austrian.com
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 23905
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 935fe58262a7e3cfd1aa5d1b5d507537d4ced7fb2768fc25 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.austrian.com.              IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.austrian.com.       61      IN      CNAME   www.austrian.com.edgekey.net.
www.austrian.com.edgekey.net. 4904 IN   CNAME   e7818.dsca.akamaiedge.net.
e7818.dsca.akamaiedge.net. 864000 IN    A       0.0.0.0

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
akamaiedge.net.         864000  IN      NS      ns0.example.net.

;; Query time: 49 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 11 22:06:15 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 193
```

The above output seems to be the `null.zone.file` file. I have tried whitelisting the domain in the `custom.whitelist.json`, but without luck. I have other whitelisted domains which do work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit:
named.conf.options:

```
options {

        querylog no;
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        listen-on { any; };
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        recursion yes;                 # enables resursive queries
        allow-query { any; };

        forwarders {
                1.1.1.1;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
        dnssec-validation auto;
};

logging {
  ...
};
```

Comment: show us your bind config and zone file

Comment: Look at your custom blacklist.

Comment: @MichaelHampton always the simplest answer, but not straight-forward :D

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

It appeared that my `custom.blacklist.json` file had the following two entries:

```
akamaiedge.net
akamaitechnologies.net
```

While it may not be obvious straight away, `www.austrian.com` uses both of the above domains. The `akamaiedge.net` is in the dig response in my original question, while the reverse DNS for `www.austrian.com` is a subdomain of `akamaitechnologies.net`.

Removing the two entries from the `custom.blacklist.json` solved the issue.